# R doSnow/foreach memory leak and too many iterations

Tags: r, foreach, memory-leaks, doparallel

**Summary of unsolved issues:**

**1. running out of memory - master process needs too much memory, but shouldn't**

I'll try to calculate a lot of combinations of a kind of arbitrary network and ran in some problem using doparralel and foreach. With a certain size of the problem there is just one process starting, even using makeCluster(3). Additionally I run out of memory (after using ~50GB - Error: Killed 9 - on a Mac). The strange thing is with the smaller size of the problem that is already quite large, it is running without any problems. I really can't make any sense out of it, why it is filling up the memory and not starting more then one process. Could it be that it is too large to calculate?

**Code:**

```
pacman::p_load(iterpc, doSNOW,data.table, gtools, e1071)
source('adj.R', chdir = TRUE)
source('mm.R', chdir = TRUE)

ptm<-proc.time()
###with n<-5 and p<-3 it is running without any problems
n<-6 #genotype length
p<-3 #phenotype length
pevo<-NULL
prob<-NULL
I = iterpc(2^p, 2^n, replace=TRUE, ordered=F) #all combinations
bgg   <- adjmatrix(n)

cl <- makeCluster(6)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

res<-foreach(elem = iter_wrapper(I,100) ,.combine='rbind') %dopar% {
gc()
rm()

  for(z in 1:nrow(elem)){

    bzz<-matmult(t(matmult(bgg,elem[z,])),elem[z,])
    size<-NULL
    for(k in 1:ncol(bzz)){
            size[k]<-length(which(elem==k))
    }

    prob<-rbind(prob,diag(bzz)/colSums(bgz)/n)
    diag(bzz)<-0
    pevo<-rbind(pevo,colSums(bzz != 0))
  }

    return(cbind(pevo,prob))    
}
proc.time()-ptm

write.table(res,'res2.txt',col.names=F,row.names=F,sep=" ")
print(object.size(res), units='auto')
gc()
rm()
```

Here is a screenshot of my Activity Monitor, one of the R processes take a lot more memory (up to 55GB):
[Activity Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FStfm.png)

Here is a screenshot of the error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahm1l.png)

**Edit 09/22:**

I've updated the Code above. It seems that using the DoSNOW packages instead of doParallel solves the problem with the processes. When using DoSNOW the correct amount of processes start. But this is opening a new problem. The foreach is running too many iterations.

I've added to functions:

1. Calculation of `bgg` with the function `adjmatrix`:

   ```
   adjmatrix <- function(n){
   require(e1071)

   combi <- bincombinations(n)
   l     <- length(combi[,1])
   bgg   <- matrix(0,l,l)

   for(i in 1:(length(combi[,1])-1)){
     for(j in (i+1):length(combi[,1])){
       check <- 0
       for(h in 1:length(combi[j,])){
         if(combi[j,h]!=combi[i,h]){
           check <- check+1
         }
       }   
       if(check==1){
         bgg[i,j] <- 1
         bgg[j,i] <- 1
       }
     }
   }
   return(bgg)
   }
   ```
2. Changed the calculation of `bzz` with the function `matmult`:

   ```
   matmult <- function(A,B){

   c <- matrix(0,nrow(A),length(B))
   for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
       for(j in 1:length(B)){
           sum <- 0
           for(k in 1:length(B)){
               if(j == B[k]){
               sum <- sum+A[i,k]}
           }
               c[i,j] <- sum
       }
   }
   return(c)
   }
   ```

**Edit 09/23:**
Solved : DoSNOW packages: foreach is running too many iterations

The cause was this part of the code:

```
if(is.null(prob)){
        prob<-diag(bzz)/size/n
    }
    else{
        prob<-rbind(prob,diag(bzz)/size/n)  
    }
    diag(bzz)<-0
    if(is.null(pevo)){
        pevo<-colSums(bzz != 0)
    }
    else{
        pevo<-rbind(pevo,colSums(bzz != 0))
    }
```

The following changes lead to the correct number of iterations (or results):

```
prob<-rbind(prob,diag(bzz)/colSums(bgz)/n)
diag(bzz)<-0
pevo<-rbind(pevo,colSums(bzz != 0))
```

Updated the Code.